# How to access those variables in a function that have been defined in another file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have defined a function `foo` in `foo.m`. The function takes an index `i`,  accesses the value `x(i)` of the array `x`, does some calculation on it and finally returns the result. The array `x` has been initialised in file `main.m`.

Is there any way by which the array can be accessed in the function `foo` without really passing the array?

Comment: Nope.  That's called [variable scope](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/01/16/nested-functions-and-variable-scope/).  Unless you declare that array outside of the function so that it is visible when you define the other function, you can't do what you're asking.  BTW, forgive me for asking, but why would you ever write a function that returns elements from an array given indices when you can simply access the elements yourself using native indexing?  That seems extraordinarily obfuscated and slow.

Comment: `foo` accesses `x(i)`, does some calculation on it, and returns the result. For brevity, I have skipped these details.

Comment: You should consider adding this to your problem statement to avoid having other people coming to the wrong conclusion (like me for example).

Comment: I would also like to add that a variable that is declared global in matlab really is global. It is not just global in the program that you run, but is **global for this instance of MATLAB** (meaning that, the variable have the same scope as MATLAB itself). The global variable will not be cleared in case of a crash, the variable will not be cleared if the program ends successfully and more importantly; If you use a global variable with the same name in another program/script, it will still refer to the same instance. The only way to clear a global variable is by doing **`clear global`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is absolutely bad practice** ... but you can define `x` as [`global`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) in `main.m` and then use it in `foo.m`

`main.m`

```
function [] = main()
%[
    global x;
    x = [72 5 8 42];

    y = foo(4);
    disp(y);
%]
end
```

`foo.m`

```
function [y] = foo(i)
%[
    global x;
    y = x(i);
%]
end
```

Again, **this is bad practice and I strongly encourage you to avoid doing this and opt to refactor your code** if you can.

**Side note** ... my opinion is that there is always a solution to avoid `global` variables ... if your question is oversimplified and if you are wondering how to pass tons of parameters inside `main.m` to sub-functions like `foo.m` without passing them all the time, you can put them in a [`structure`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) so you only need to pass 1 parameter:

```
function [] = main()
%[
    % Parameters
    parameters.x = [7 5 8 42];
    parameters.window = "Hamming";
    ...

    % Computations
    y = foo(i, parameters);
%]
end

function [y] = foo(i, parameters)
%[
    y = parameters.x(i);
%]
end
```

Again, this all depends on your situation, but **please consider reviewing your code structure before to use** `global`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. The solution is called **global variables** and is in almost every case not recommended. I strongly recommend that you keep passing the vector to foo by arguments. Global variables are not evil, but they can cause a serious amount of troubles. Matlab have actually tried to make globals easier to use, but it is not possible to solve all the problems the can cause. I just read a good [article](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/) about that.

The simplest case where this can cause trouble is if you modify x inside this function. Other users need to dig into the code of `foo` to be able understand what happens. What if foo would perform an advanced mathematical calculation and the function is 200 rows long.

Before you use a global. First you need to ask yourself, **does all functions really need to access this variable?**

I assume that the example you gave is not the real problem you have since the same can be accomplished with,

```
x = [1,2,3,4];
idx = 3;
x3 = x(3);
```

so there may be another reason you want to use a global. However, using globals to not be forced to pass the function with a parameter is not a good reason (sorry). Using a parameter will be an advantage for any other person reading the code, since it helps adding to the function description. Eg. "This function returns the index of a vector that can be passed to the function". It would then be really easy to understand what the function does.